# Add x-rate-limit response headers to the load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rate-limiting, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-armor

I configured a Cloud Armor [rate limiting rule](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview) and i would like to attach the following custom response headers to my global external HTTP(S) load balancer backend.

`x-ratelimit-limit`: The maximum number of requests available in the current time frame.
`x-ratelimit-remaining`: The number of remaining requests in the current time frame.
`x-ratelimit-reset`: A UNIX timestamp of the expected time when the rate limit will reset.

In the [custom headers documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers-global) no rate limit variable seems to exist. There is however a notice about Cloud Armor Response Headers further down:

> You can configure Google Cloud Armor to insert a custom header and value.

I found the [--request-headers-to-add](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/security-policies/rules/update#--request-headers-to-add) rule setting but i need some way to access the current Cloud Armor rate limit values.

Is my use case not possible or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Cloud Function to retrieve Cloud Armor rate limit values to do this:

- Create a code with Cloud Function which retrieves the Cloud Armor rate limit values and sets the custom response headers. Use [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library) for this and deploy the code into your project.
- Now configure your global external HTTP(S) load balancer to route requests through the Cloud Function. Create a backend service which points to the Cloud Function URL and then add backend service to the load balancer backend configuration. Please check [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am not quite sure i understand you correctly. I am not interested in the rate limit configuration values i placed in the policy rule itself. I need to know how many requests a specific IP still has left, until the cloud armor rate limit is enforced.

Comment: Please check with Cloud Armor REST API for the number of requests for a specific IP. Use securityPolicies.getRule to retrieve the rate limiting rule for your Cloud Armor policy and securityPolicies,query for the remaining requests or the specific IP address.

Comment: Ah thank you, i somehow missed these API endpoints. Isn't this "middleware" cloud function really expensive in terms of latency.